# CodeIgniter not executing the PHP script called by $.get()

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have a sample script written using CodeIgniter and I used JQuery's `$.get()` function. `$.get()` called this PHP script: **delete.php**

```
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'table1');
    $qry = "delete from table1 where id = $id";
    $qry_result = mysqli_query($conn, $qry);
```

How I call delete.php in JQuery: `$.get("delete.php", { id : my_id} );`. My problem is that delete.php was not executed by `$.get()`. I am thinking if the cause was due to CodeIgniter's security that you cannot access the scripts directly?

Please help!

Comment: Look in the network tab of the Chrome Dev tools (or Safari or firefox). Are the requests actually being sent?

Comment: Why are you using `mysqli_*` in Codeigniter?

Comment: @undefined - Please ignore `mysqli`, my site is configured to run this version but the query / PHP script is working fine.

Comment: Okay, you are using a MVC framework, it is not how it's supposed to work, you should use your Controllers and Models, what you are doing is an anti-pattern.

Comment: is it a codeigniter way...!!!

Comment: @Alfo - Yes the request is being sent, I checked it in Chrome and I got this from the console: `http://localhost/mysite/index.php/site/delete.php?id=820 404 (Not Found) `. I am new to CodeIgniter so please bear with me. I've put my **delete.php** on the same directory as the one that uses `$.get()`.

Comment: you never call a direct script in codeigniter you need to call a controller via URL then it will do the rest of the part

Comment: Okay I understand, now how can I do that? I am new to CodeIgniter.

Comment: CodeIgniter has a good user guide, http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/overview/getting_started.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all if you are new to this MVC framework then at least go and study the introduction & tutorial part for there user guide http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/.

Then only you will come to know how to call a controller in that.

But if you want the answer then you can do this in this way:

1.first go and create a controller(e.g. mycontroller) & write a function inside it(e.g. myfunction) and write your code into that part & it is also better that you do not user this mysqli* stuff in MVC.

2.pass the url(e.g. http://[yourhost]/index.php/mycontroller/myfunction) inside `$.get()` function.

P.S. I am not sure that your CI is configured to use index.php in URL or not. It totally depends upon your configuration. So if it not work for you then try without index.php or take a look into routs.php

Comment: I got it working before you posted your answer, but still thank you for your help.